# How to add numerical index to column in python using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have tried to add a numerical index for 81 columns in python so that I can use the index values to find out one particular column's 'set' value in order to analyze data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QERlg.png)

Comment: Please add your example code/dataframe as text in the actual quesiton

Comment: Do you mean using `.iloc`... eg:.... `df.iloc[:, 0]`... will give you the first column.... `df.iloc[:, 80]` will give you the 81st? (`df.iloc[:, 0:4]` will give you the 1st-5th.... etc...)

Comment: I want a new index above the column name. I used .iloc to extract a particular column to find out the 'set' values of that column but for that, I need the index value of all columns so I can easily extract any column to analyze #(here in place of -25 I want to use any index values of column among numbers of columns but I counted all 81 columns to find out the index value . example that -25 which is used in the program) ."df_dwty=df_asset.iloc[:,-25] df_dwtys=set(df_dwty) df_dwtys

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.